# $scope.$apply and ng-include

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I'm using a $scope.$apply to trigger the view to update based on a changed variable in the scope.  However, I have another line in the html that is an ng-include,

```
<div data-ng-include data-ng-src="'views/partials/_menubar.html'"></div>
```

[error message](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%22fn%3a%20function%20%28%29%7Bvar%20a%3Dd.url%28%29,b%3Dh.%24%24replace%3Bk%26%26a%3D%3Dh.absUrl%28%29%7C%7C%28k%2B%2B,c.%24evalAsync%28function%28%29%7Bc.%24broadcast%28%5C%22%24locationChangeStart%5C%22,%5Cnh.absUrl%28%29,a%29.defaultPrevented%3Fh.%24%24parse%28a%29%3a%28d.url%28h.absUrl%28%29,b%29,g%28a%29%29%7D%29%29%3Bh.%24%24replace%3D!1%3Breturn%20k%7D%3B%20newVal%3a%208%3B%20oldVal%3a%207%22%5D,%5B%22fn%3a%20function%20%28%29%7Bvar%20a%3Dd.url%28%29,b%3Dh.%24%24replace%3Bk%26%26a%3D%3Dh.absUrl%28%29%7C%7C%28k%2B%2B,c.%24evalAsync%28function%28%29%7Bc.%24broadcast%28%5C%22%24locationChangeStart%5C%22,%5Cnh.absUrl%28%29,a%29.defaultPrevented%3Fh.%24%24parse%28a%29%3a%28d.url%28h.absUrl%28%29,b%29,g%28a%29%29%7D%29%29%3Bh.%24%24replace%3D!1%3Breturn%20k%7D%3B%20newVal%3a%209%3B%20oldVal%3a%208%22%5D,%5B%22fn%3a%20function%20%28%29%7Bvar%20a%3Dd.url%28%29,b%3Dh.%24%24replace%3Bk%26%26a%3D%3Dh.absUrl%28%29%7C%7C%28k%2B%2B,c.%24evalAsync%28function%28%29%7Bc.%24broadcast%28%5C%22%24locationChangeStart%5C%22,%5Cnh.absUrl%28%29,a%29.defaultPrevented%3Fh.%24%24parse%28a%29%3a%28d.url%28h.absUrl%28%29,b%29,g%28a%29%29%7D%29%29%3Bh.%24%24replace%3D!1%3Breturn%20k%7D%3B%20newVal%3a%2010%3B%20oldVal%3a%209%22%5D,%5B%22fn%3a%20function%20%28%29%7Bvar%20a%3Dd.url%28%29,b%3Dh.%24%24replace%3Bk%26%26a%3D%3Dh.absUrl%28%29%7C%7C%28k%2B%2B,c.%24evalAsync%28function%28%29%7Bc.%24broadcast%28%5C%22%24locationChangeStart%5C%22,%5Cnh.absUrl%28%29,a%29.defaultPrevented%3Fh.%24%24parse%28a%29%3a%28d.url%28h.absUrl%28%29,b%29,g%28a%29%29%7D%29%29%3Bh.%24%24replace%3D!1%3Breturn%20k%7D%3B%20newVal%3a%2011%3B%20oldVal%3a%2010%22%5D,%5B%22fn%3a%20function%20%28%29%7Bvar%20a%3Dd.url%28%29,b%3Dh.%24%24replace%3Bk%26%26a%3D%3Dh.absUrl%28%29%7C%7C%28k%2B%2B,c.%24evalAsync%28function%28%29%7Bc.%24broadcast%28%5C%22%24locationChangeStart%5C%22,%5Cnh.absUrl%28%29,a%29.defaultPrevented%3Fh.%24%24parse%28a%29%3a%28d.url%28h.absUrl%28%29,b%29,g%28a%29%29%7D%29%29%3Bh.%24%24replace%3D!1%3Breturn%20k%7D%3B%20newVal%3a%2012%3B%20oldVal%3a%2011%22%5D%5D)

When I remove the ng-include and replace it with a static call there is no error.  Here is the template that I'm including as well:

```
<div class="menu" ng-controller="MenuController">
    <div style="display: inline-block">
        Hello!
    </div>
    <ul class="menu_dropdown">
        <li class="menu_item">Test1</li>
        <li class="menu_item">Test2</li>
        <li class="menu_item">Test3</li>
    </ul>       
</div>
```

The code for menu controller is

```
app.controller('MenuController', function($scope) {
});
```

Comment: Does your template include itself recursively? You have an infinite loop going on somewhere. You should probably post the template.

Comment: You're only getting the error when you include the template, and the only logic in your template is in your MenuController, so the problem probably originates from there. You'll need to post the MenuController as well it seems.

Comment: @dustyrockpyle updated again, its pretty bare bones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with ng-include was actually a red herring.  The real problem was trying to change the `window.history`, as seen in the thread [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3924).  My guess is because the ng-include directive references $location when it attempts to get resources.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-src` is used to allow elements that usually have a src (like anchors or images) to apply the src tag only after angular's digest, not for inclusion of templates in `ng-include`. See [ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) docs and [ng-src](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) docs.

A safe way to specify the src using `ng-include` would be like this:

```
<div data-ng-include="src='views/partials/_menubar.html'"></div>
```

or

```
<div data-ng-include="'views/partials/_menubar.html'"></div>
```

If you *must* have the src separately, it's `data-src` and not `data-ng-src`:

```
<div data-ng-include data-src="'views/partials/_menubar.html'"></div>
```

see [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2VklKDu09InLTXKrVNrp).

edit: To address your error message.. you'll see that message if you've bound a function to the scope which changes every time it is called.

For example, this will cause such an error:

```
// controller
$scope.getQuote = function(){
    return 'someViewName' + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) + '.html';
};

// view
<div data-ng-include="{{getQuote}}"></div>
```